# What is the difference between Map.putAll() and Map.clone() methods?

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

I'm want to figure out what's the pros and cons of these two methods.

I tried to find out about that here and on some other sites, but I haven't found this particular information.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Maps {
    private Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();

private void initialization() {
    map.put(1, "Hello");
    map.put(2, "everyone!");
    map.put(3, "Nice to");
    map.put(4, "meet you");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Maps exe = new Maps();
    exe.initialization();
    exe.map2.putAll(exe.map);
    exe.map3 = (Map<Integer, String>) exe.map2.clone();
    System.out.println(exe.map2.values());
    System.out.println(exe.map3.values());

}
```

}

I get the same result, but I'm interested what the situation I should use one or the other method.

Comment: They just don't do the same thing at all. putAll puts all the elements of a map into another map. clone creates a copy (a clone) of the map. The same difference there is between writing something on a piece of paper and xeroxing a piece of paper.

Comment: You are using two different methods in a way that accomplishes the same thing. However consider if `map2` already has three elements and then you used `addAll`. Then `map2` and `map3` would not be equal

Answer (score 1):

`Map.putAll()` adds all the mappings from the argument to the *existing* map on which it is invoked.  Where the target map already has mappings for the same keys, the original mappings will be replaced.  Mappings for all other keys will be retained.

In general, one must assume that `Map.clone()` will throw a `CloneNotSupportedException`, as that is the behavior inherited from class `Object`, and the `Map` interface does not specify different behavior.  However, `HashMap` in particular provides a `clone()` method that creates a new, shallow copy of the map on which it is invoked.  Note well that there is a big difference between creating a new map, as `HashMap.clone()` does, and adding entries to an existing map, as `Map.putAll()` does, though it is of less significance in the case where the target map of the `putAll()` is initially empty.

When you want to create a copy of a `Map`, it is usually best to choose an appropriate implementation class and instantiate it via a constructor that accepts the source map as a parameter.  Such a constructor is not guaranteed to be present, but it is strongly recommended for general-purpose `Map` implementations, and every such implementation in the Java standard library offers one.  Instantiating a new, empty, map and then using `putAll()` to populate it is another option. Using `clone()` safely requires that you know that you're using a `Map` implementation that supports it, so it is rare that you can safely `clone()` but cannot instantiate a suitable map normally.